# Make all the buttons do the same things?

Tags: vb.net, button

I'm new to vb and gui programming. I want a group of buttons on my form do exactly the same things when some action is performed, such as a click. I found some methods in this question[How do I make buttons do the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754823/how-do-i-make-buttons-do-the-same-thing).According to it, I wrote some codes and they did work.

```
 Private Sub Answers_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.MouseDown, Button2.MouseDown, Button3.MouseDown
    MessageBox.Show("Hi!")
End Sub
```

The question is that now I have more buttons(10 or more), and I don't want to write codes like Button1.MouseDown, Button2.MouseDown, Button3.MouseDown...etc. Is there any methods to avoid this? For example use an arrary? thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have, is the shortest method,   you will need to name the buttons in the array so its not going to be any shorter

Any GUI with redundant buttons is not a good GUI.

Comment: Thanks! I need to perform some drags. It is designed as a recognize and drag to match problem. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Add your Controls to an Array of type of Button or to a List then you can iterate through the collection dynamically adding your event handlers. You will then be able to get the instance of the button that was clicked by casting the sender to a button.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myButtons As List(Of Button) = New List(Of Button)
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        myButtons.Add(Button1)
        myButtons.Add(Button2)
        myButtons.Add(Button3)
        myButtons.Add(Button4)
        myButtons.Add(Button5)
        myButtons.Add(Button6)
        For Each btn As Button In myButtons
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf myButtonClick 'Add your eventhandlers
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub myButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        'Do what ever you need to do to the calling control
    End Sub

End Class
```